# Are metrics uniformly equivalent if and only if they have the same zero-distance sets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, uniform-spaces, equivalent-metrics

Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be two metrics on the same set $X$. Then $d_1$ and $d_2$ are uniformly equivalent if the identity maps $i:(M,d_1)\rightarrow(M,d_2)$ and $i^{-1}:(M,d_2)\rightarrow(M,d_1)$ are uniformly continuous.  My question is, are two metric spaces uniformly equivalent if and only if they have the same zero distance sets?  That is, $d_1(A,B)=0$ if and only if $d_2(A,B)=0$ for all subsets $A$ and $B$ of $M$.

Or to put it in fancier language, do two metrics induce the same [uniformity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) if and only if they induce the same [proximity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_space)?  If not, which direction is false?

For those who don’t know, $d_1(A,B)=\inf\{d_1(a,b):a\in A, b\in B\}$, and similarly for $d_2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.** I found the result stated as an exercise in [this excerpt](http://gdurl.com/Q3yQ) from Ryszard Engelking's book General Topology:

> 8.5.19. A. Let $(X,\rho)$ and $(Y,\sigma)$ be metric spaces and let $\delta$ and $\delta'$ denote the proximities induced by $\rho$ and $\sigma$ on $X$ and $Y$ respectively. Show that a mapping $f$ of $X$ to $Y$ is proximally continuous if and only if $f$ is uniformly continuous with respect to $\rho$ and $\sigma$. 
>   B. **Note that the metric[s] $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$ on a set $X$ are uniformly equivalent if and only if they induce the same proximity.**

Here proximally continuous means that the images of two sets which are close with respect to $\rho$ are close with respect to $\sigma$.

So two metrics induce the same uniformity if and only if they induce the same proximity.  Which I think means that metrizable uniformities and metrizable proximities can be viewed as fundamentally the same structure.