# Is every completely regular topology induced by some proximity?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

A [proximity space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_space) is a set endowed with a relation defining a notion of when two subsets are near or far apart.  A proximity space induces a topology, and such a topology is always completely regular.  But I’m wondering if the converse is true.

My question is, is every completely regular topology induced by some proximity?  Or is being “proximatizable” a stronger condition than being completely regular?

My motive for asking this question, by the way, is to understand the relation between proximity spaces and [uniform spaces](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space).  Because a topology is completely regular if and only if it is induced by a uniformity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any completely regular space is induced by a proximity space and also by a uniformity. It's all the same class topologically. Engelking devotes one chapter in his book General Topology on these notions and equivalences.

Comment: Thanks.  By the way, can you take a look at my question here? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3110208/71829